# C++ Derived classes only using part of inherited base constructor

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor

I am certain that this is a basic question but I have not been able to find the answer anywhere.  Let's say I have a base class with constructor:

```
class Parent{
public:
    double propertyA, propertyB;
    Parent(double propertyA, double propertyB){
        this->propertyA = propertyA;
        this->propertyB = propertyB;
}
};
```

and then I want a derived class to use this base constructor but it will only need to take in `propertyB`. `propertyA` will end up being a constant (let's say `1.0`).

Currently I am trying:

```
class Child : public Parent {
public:
    Child(double PropertyB): Parent(1.0, PropertyB) {}
};
```

I am not certain that this behaves as I want it to though. Is this how I should be doing this?

Comment: What exactly makes you unsure about the behavior? How exactly to you think it does, and what do you want? Did you notice any particular problems in practice?

Comment: If you are doing polymorphism, Parent should have a virtual destructor and probably one-or-more virtual functions.  If instead you are doing composition-by-inheritance, Child should inherit Parent privately or protected, not publicly — but I recommend having Parent as a private member variable in Child rather that composition-by-inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply overload the constructor. Code should be like this -

```
class Parent{
public:
    double propertyA, propertyB;
    Parent(double propertyA, double propertyB){
        this->propertyA = propertyA;
        this->propertyB = propertyB;
    }
    Parent(double propertyB){ 
        this->propertyA = 1.0; // constant value
        this->propertyB = propertyB;
    }
};
class Child : public Parent {
public:
    Child(double PropertyB): Parent(PropertyB) {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to be sure is to test, I think:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Parent
{
public:
    double propertyA, propertyB;
    Parent(double propertyA, double propertyB)
    {
        this->propertyA = propertyA;
        this->propertyB = propertyB;
    }
};
class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    Child(double PropertyB): Parent(1.0, PropertyB) {}
    double getPropertyA()
    {
        return propertyA;
    }
    double getPropertyB()
    {
        return propertyB;
    }
};

int main()
{
    double a = 3.0;
    double b = 5.0;
    Parent* parent = new Parent(a,b);
    Child* child = new Child(b);
    std::cout << "PropertyA for child " << child->getPropertyA();
}
```

The output is :

```sh
1
```